# tsd install jquery --save Doesn't Install When Run

Tags: jquery, typescript, installation, tsd

I've just started learning TypeScript, and I'm making a project that requires me to run `tsd install jquery --save`. When I ran that command, I received an error saying "The type definition `index.d.ts` does not exist. Create one and try again."

I've googled the error and I found that the command has updated to `typings` instead of `tsd` instead. Not sure if that's correct, however.

I then tried running `typings install jquery --save` but that didn't work either.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tsd` utility is deprecated, but you can install types directly using NPM.

All of the official types from Definitely Typed can be found in the `@types` organisation.

```
npm install --save @types/jquery
```

There is a [type search available on Definitely Typed](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/).